# JSON and iOS and string data

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem with my attempt to show data in JSON UITableViewDataSource
The data from JSON are:

```
[
 "Jon",
 "Bill",
 "Kristan"
]
```

JSON itself has gone through the validator.
The error I have is TableViews [2050: f803] Illegal start of token [h]

Here is my code

```
NSString *myRawJson = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://site.com/json.php"];

if ([myRawJson length] == 0){
    return; 
}
NSError *error = nil;
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
tableData =[[parser objectWithString:myRawJson error:&error] copy];
NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

list  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Johan", @"Polo", @"Randi", @"Tomy", nil];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't fetch the JSON data from the URL. Instead you try to parse the URL itself.

Comment: Can an example? I fear not you do not understand.